# Pass parameter from shell script to SQL script

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus, ksh

I have ksh script which is calling a SQL script called `report.sql`.

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus swb/swb4gdeprod@gdeprod  @$reportHome/report.sql
```

Currently this SQL script is fetching data for sysdate from the database.

I want to pass a date as input to the SQL script so that it picks data corresponding to that date instead of sysdate.

How can I pass a date from ksh to SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 3):

[With substitution variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#CACIIEDF); `start` is equivalent to `@` here.

You haven't shown the SQL your report contains, but assuming at some point you have something like:

```
where some_col > trunc(sysdate)
```

you would change that to:

```
where some_col > to_date('&1', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and then pass a date string *in the same format* on the command line:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus swb/swb4gdeprod@gdeprod @$reportHome/report.sql 2016-07-27
```

The value you pass in, e.g. `2016-07-27`, is the first positional parameter so it can be referenced as a substitution variable using `&1`. As it's a string that has to be enclosed in single quotes when you reference it in SQL. And because it's a string you have to convert it to a date. The format of the string you pass in has to match the format you specify with the `to_date()` function.

Also be wary of passing in month names as you may hit language issues at some point, and ideally you'd use a format that is unambiguous. I've used the ISO format YYYY-MM-DD, and if you stick with that you could also use [a date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062) as the substitution will be done by SQL*Plus before it is interpreted by the SQL engine:

```
where some_col > date '&1'
```